# about field update using function with case

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to update some field value depending two string field using a function with `If` and `Case`, function below:

```vb
Private Function checkDATI(tipotransazione As String, tipovendita As String) As String

Dim r As String
r = ""
If tipotransazione = "VENDITA" Then
    Select Case tipovendita
        Case "ARMI"
            If Me.txtMatricola = "" Then r = "Matricola"
            If Me.txtModello = "" Then r = "Modello"
            If Me.txtCalibro = "" Then r = "Calibro"
            If Me.txtTipoArma = "" Then r = "Tipo Arma"
            If Me.txtFabrica = "" Then r = "Fabbrica"
        Case "VENDITA ARMI/MUNIZIONI"
        Case "MUNIZIONI"
    End Select
End If

If tipotransazione = "ACQUISTO" Then
    Select Case tipovendita
        Case "ARMI"
            If Me.txtMatricola = "" Then r = "Matricola"
            If Me.txtModello = "" Then r = "Modello"
            If Me.txtCalibro = "" Then r = "Calibro"
            If Me.txtTipoArma = "" Then r = "Tipo Arma"
            If Me.txtFabrica = "" Then r = "Fabbrica"
        Case "VENDITA ARMI/MUNIZIONI"
        Case "MUNIZIONI"
    End Select
End If

checkDATI = r

End Function
```

And then when I call this function in a command button event as:

```vb
MsgBox (checkDATI(Me.CausaleMov, Me.txt_tipomov))
```

It's not updating that field. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that the values contained in `Me.CausaleMov` and `Me.txt_tipomov` do not get changed?

Comment: no no, not that, if Me.CausaleMov and Me.txt_tipomov get value and value match the case "ARMI" then all mentioned field to be update that are in if statements.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```vb
If Me.txtMatricola = "" Then r = "Matricola"
```

What you are doing is assigning the value: `"Matricola"` to the variable:`r`. Instead what I think you want is this:

```vb
If Me.txtMatricola = "" Then Me.txtMatricola  = "Matricola"
```

This actually sets the value of the field: `txtMatricola` to `"Matricola"`.  This goes for all of the fields that are in your `Case` statements.